# x61 Fingerprint Reader as a scanner?

Tags: thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I've got an x61 tablet pc with fingerprint reader, and I want a way to see the image(?) scanned when I swipe my finger. Obviously I can use it for login - I don't really care about that, it's easier for me to type my password. I just want to be able to see the fingerprint it gets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The X61 series [uses](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Integrated_Fingerprint_Reader) a UPEK Touchstrip fingerprint reader that, when using Linux drivers, [does hardware image processing](http://reactivated.net/fprint/wiki/Upekts#Device_operation) and then returns a status to the computer. Due to this design there is no way for you to access the scanned image.

With that said, there is [evidence](http://reactivated.net/fprint/wiki/Upekts#Other_capabilities) that with proprietary Windows drivers the device operates in a different mode that is capable of returning a scanned image, but it doesn't looks like there's been any development done in this area.